# How to sharing classes code in different SWFs?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swc

I am working on a Flash project. In the project there are lots of isolated FLA files which may share the same common classes code. To clarify the project limitation:

1. I could **ONLY** use Flash CS6 IDE. No modern tool such as Flash Builder or Flex, just pure Flash CS6 IDE.
2. I have to export the FLAs to SWFs one by one separately so each one of SWFs would contains a copy of the ABC of the common classes.
3. I have a loader.swf which was going to load all the other SWFs into a same ApplicationDomain. In other words all the duplicated ABC in the SWFs would be ignored because the loader.swf has also already involved that.

And my questions are:

1. Is there any way I could pre-compile all the common classes into a SWC or SWF and I could use it just like a DLL or SO?
2. If so how could I create such a SWC or SWF only by Flash CS6 IDE as I told before?
3. If I could create such a SWC or SWF how should I use it? Such as How could I change my configuration in the Flash CS6 IDE?

To be honest I don't know my idea is valid or not. Please, any advise would be great helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: you can create a SWC by selecting "Export SWC" in publish settings

Comment: Thanks, I got the SWC finally. But how should I use it as a dynamic sharing library?

Comment: oh i see - if you need dynamic runtime loading, SWCs are no good

Comment: I want to use SWC as a static lib just like a .lib in c++ and use SWF as the real class provider just like the a .dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Create a FLA which would touch all the common classes
2. Exrpot the FLA I would get two files: SWF and SWC
3. Use the SWC as "External Library" in other FLAs
4. Use the SWF as Run-time Sharing Library to dynamic load it at run-time